# Use the passport.authenticate('local') Library to Generate a Cookie without a Client Call

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

How can I use the passport.authenticate('local') library to generate a cookie on the server side, without using any post calls from the client side? Basically, the passport function is typically called from the client side using the following express route:

```
 app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
      ...
 })
```

Which triggers the following passport.use code:

```
 passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
  ...
 }
```

Since my users are already authenticated on the server side, I only wish to use the passport library to generate a cookie and send it to the client. How can this be done without triggering the process via the post call above?

I have tried this, but without success:

```
 passport.authenticate('local'), (req = { id: id, password: 'pw' }, res) => {
    res.send(result.user)
 }
```

Comment: If you want the server to communicate with the client you need some sort of request client-side

Comment: Thank you Daniel_Knights. I am initiating a call from the client, but for another route.

Comment: No problem @JF0001. When you say the user's already been authenticated server-side, do you send authentication data back with the response? A token or credentials or something?

Comment: Well, I am actually using MetaMask to authenticate the user. On an initial post request from the client, I initially send a nonce from the server, which the client signs with MetaMask, and then, after validating the signed nonce, I would like to send a cookie so that the server knows that the client has already authenticated on subsequent calls to the server.

Comment: I could always send a subsequent post to the server in order to obtain the cookie, but I felt that this wouldn't be the most efficient, considering that I have already authenticated the client on the server. J

Comment: Looking into the passport-local docs seems that you have to call passport.authenticate on each request you need authentication for

Comment: Otherwise, I'd suggest using JWT's instead

Comment: Yes, that might be a better choice. Thank you again very much for your time and help Daniel_Knights!